# Proftpd - (Login failed): Invalid shell: '/dev/null'

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, ftp

I'm using proftpd. When I try to log into the the FTP server it gives me the below message in the log:

```
USER Err (Login failed): Invalid shell: '/dev/null'
```

Many searches reveal that I should set `RequireValidShell` to off which I did, then I got this error in the log:

```
Err chdir("/dev/null"): Not a directory
```

I also tried to set my shell access to '/dev/false' and that didn't change anything. Client side, it says the login failed. I'm not sure what to do anymore, I spent about 4 hours trying to figure it out. Could really use some help.

Here is my proftpd.conf:

```
Include /etc/proftpd/modules.conf
UseIPv6             on
IdentLookups            off
ServerName          "192.168.0.100"
ServerType          standalone
RequireValidShell       off
DeferWelcome            off
MultilineRFC2228        on
DefaultServer           on
ShowSymlinks            on
TimeoutNoTransfer       600
TimeoutStalled          600
TimeoutIdle             600
DisplayLogin                    welcome.msg
DisplayChdir                .message true
ListOptions                 "-l"
DenyFilter          \*.*/
Port                21
<IfModule mod_dynmasq.c>
</IfModule>
MaxInstances            3
User                proftpd
Group               nogroup
Umask               022  022
AllowOverwrite          on
TransferLog         /var/log/proftpd/xferlog
SystemLog               /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log
<IfModule mod_quotatab.c>
QuotaEngine             off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ratio.c>
Ratios              off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_delay.c>
DelayEngine             on
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ctrls.c>
ControlsEngine          off
ControlsMaxClients      2
ControlsLog         /var/log/proftpd/controls.log
ControlsInterval        5
ControlsSocket          /var/run/proftpd/proftpd.sock
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ctrls_admin.c>
AdminControlsEngine     off
</IfModule>
Include /etc/proftpd/conf.d/
```

- PRoFTPD-1.3.4a
- Xubuntu 12.10

Comment: It would likely mean that `/dev/null` is not listed in your `/etc/shells` file. You can manually add to `/etc/shells`, but it isn't the best option. Change `RequireValidShell       off` to `RequireValidShell       no`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the person who configured the account was just as misguided when assigning a home directory as they were when they assigned the shell.

That could explain why it's failing to chdir when they successfully log in to the FTP service.

`grep [username] /etc/passwd` will show if the user's home directory was set as inappropriately as the shell. `sudo usermod -d /home/[username] -s /usr/sbin/nologin [username]` could set a sane shell and home for the account. You might also need to `sudo mkdir -p /home/[username]` and `sudo chown [username] /home/[username]`.